# Token configuration for multiple workspace slack app

Tags: slack-api

If I want my app to be distributed to multiple workspaces, how will I then manage my tokens? I cannot hard-code the same token as it is unique for each workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You'll make use of the 'redirect url' to capture generated token and store it in a cache or db depending on your implementation.

Following documentation may help:

1. https://slack.dev/java-slack-sdk/guides/app-distribution
2. https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2